# EF: Cannot insert value NULL into column 'ID'

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Trying to insert a row into my database using Entity Framework. I assign all of the values upon insert except ID, which is the primary key, and I'd like it to get auto-incremented by the SQL Server DB.

My table definition/class:

```
public partial class T_SurfacePick
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int? BoreholeID { get; set; }
    public int? AuthoredNameID { get; set; }
    public int? LoadFormat { get; set; }
    public double? PickDepth { get; set; }
    public int? OwningAuthorID { get; set; }
    public int? QualityID { get; set; }
    public double? CustomData { get; set; }
}
```

When I call the `SaveChanges()` method, I get an error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID'

How do I get this column to auto-increment itself? I'd like not to have to worry about keeping track of the `ID` and assigning it myself.

I'm trying to use the code-first approach. Here's an example of part of my decision tree for inserts/updates:

```
if (MenefeePick == null) // New top
{
   var Pick = new T_SurfacePick { BoreholeID = Wellbore.ID, AuthoredNameID = MenefeeAN.ID, LoadFormat = 1, PickDepth = Menefee, OwningAuthorID = ProgAuthor.ID, QualityID = -1, CustomData = null };
   db.T_SurfacePick.Add(Pick);
}
else // Update top
{
    MenefeePick.PickDepth = Menefee;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

I'll further qualify by mentioning that my model uses an existing database from a software product.

Comment: Do you have it set as `IDENTITY` on the server?

Comment: Make the column as Primary key and set it to AUTO INCREMENT.

Comment: set identity in row. like this

(id int primary key identity(1,1))

Comment: Can you show your table's schema, please?

Comment: Please add some more info.What EF approach are you using(code-first,database-first...). Also give an example of the code you are using to insert a record in the db.

Comment: @JRLambert, How do I check that?

Comment: @Durgpal Where should that statement be in code?

Comment: When you create a table then use this code to set id as primary key and set auto identity

Answer (score 0):

İf Model first try block

```
[Key]
 [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
 public Int64 PolicyID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -3):

Define `ID` as `int? ID`. With `?` the variable will accept `null`.

Comment: This is probably not what the op is looking for. Why would he want a null value as an id?

Comment: Don't know why, but the question is that "Cannot insert value NULL into column ID".

Comment: Please read the question again. The error message is *cannot insert value NULL*. The **question** is *How do I get this column to auto-increment itself?*

Comment: The code shows the column is the 'Key' but also Database Generated so maybe but a Zero in the ID column and let it get changed on INSERT